# Google Maps Error says I must specify location

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I've been trying to solve this problem for a while to no avail.
so I use the W3C standard geolocation to pull my position, then I assign that to another variable:

```
 navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
  var pos = {
    lat: position.coords.latitude,
    lng: position.coords.longitude
  };

  currentLocation = pos;

  infoWindow.setPosition(pos);
  infoWindow.setContent('Location found.');
  map.setCenter(pos);
}, function() {
  handleLocationError(true, infoWindow, map.getCenter());
});
} else {
  // Browser doesn't support Geolocation
  handleLocationError(false, infoWindow, map.getCenter());
}
```

`currentLocation` is defined globally.
My location is found, but then when I try to perform a radar search, it fails and throws the error: 'Uncaught error: Missing Parameter. You must specify location.'

here is my radar search

```
function performSearch() {
  var request = {
    location: currentLocation,
    radius: searchRadius,
    type: ['restaurant']
  };
  service.radarSearch(request, callback);
}

function callback(results, status) {
        if (status !== google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {
          console.error(status);
          return;
        }
        for (var i = 0, result; result = results[i]; i++) {
          addMarker(result);
        }
}
```

Comment: When you use a debugger, does the value of `request` look correct to you?

Comment: No it is returning `undefined`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that currentLocation is not set at the time performSearch is executed. I was able to reproduce the error with a JSFiddle on my end by defining, but not setting a global variable and then using that variable in performSearch() prior to setting it. I received the same error as you.

One way you could fix this would be to make sure performSearch is executed after the variable, currentLocation, has been set. I'm not sure where you currently call performSearch(), but if you modify your code to call it in your first function like so, I believe it will work:

```
 navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
 var pos = {
   lat: position.coords.latitude,
   lng: position.coords.longitude
 };

 currentLocation = pos;

 infoWindow.setPosition(pos);
 infoWindow.setContent('Location found.');
 map.setCenter(pos);
 performSearch();
}
```

I hope this helps!